# ¿como mostrar una palabra pero cada letra aumentada en 3?

Tags: java

Necesito hacer un programa que al ingresar una palabra me muestre esa palabra pero cada letra aumentada en 3 si ingreso `"hola"` que me muestre `"krñd"`

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega qué has intentado para resolver el problema o qué es lo que te bloquea para culminarla.

Comment: ¿En que lenguaje?, ¿tienes algo de código ya hecho?, publicalo y te ayudo se me hace fácil tu problema.

Comment: @MaghdielCampos el lenguaje es Java puede ver al final de la pregunta el tag java. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Cogerías el `String` con la palabra y, ya que un `String` es una matriz de `chars`, los separas uno a uno, los conviertes a `int`, les sumas 3 y los vuelves a convertir en String:

```
String palabra="hola";
String nuevaPalabra="";
for(int i=0;i<palabra.length;i++){
   char letra= palabra.charAt[i];
   int j= (int)letra;
   int nuevaJ=j+3;
   char nuevaLetra= (char)nuevaJ;  
   nuevaPalabra+=nuevaLetra;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente recorres la palabra introducida con un for iterando por cada caracter y con una matriz con el abecedario vas buscando las posiciones.

Aquí un ejemplo completo.

```
try {
                    String[] abc=new String[]{"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","ñ","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    String texto="";
                    String resultado="";

                    do{
                        System.out.println("Introduce la palabra:");
                        texto=br.readLine();
                        texto=texto.toLowerCase();
                        resultado="";
                        for(int i=0;i<texto.length();i++){
                            resultado+=abc[Arrays.asList(abc).indexOf(String.valueOf(texto.charAt(i)))+3];
                        }
                        System.out.println("Resultado: "+resultado);
                    }while(!texto.equals("0"));


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getClass()+" --> "+e.getMessage());
                }
```